# Why can't i activate facetime on my ipod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, facetime

i have a new ipod touch and i am on a wifi connection but whenever i try to use facetime i get this error:

"Can't connect to facetime, please check your network"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer.  you have to go into:

Settings
WIFI
and click on your wireless router and change the DNS to 8.8.8.8

Comment: You set the DNS to the Google's DNS. It was then probably DNS-related but could also work with other DNS as I think (and I hope) that Google is not the only DNS pointing correctly ro the facetime servers! :)